# Set RootViewController in UINavigationController class - Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, rootviewcontroller

I am new working with Objective C, I have good knowledge with storyboards but now I try to change the root view controller of a UINavigationController by code, it happens that it depends on a variable, I will set the root, but I don't know how to configure this action besides what I have my custom class for my UINavigationControllers. I hope you can help me.Keep in mind that this view is the 3rd screen in the app.

[image]

```
@interface PCCatalogNavigationController () <UINavigationControllerDelegate>

@end

@implementation PCCatalogNavigationController

- (void)viewDidLoad{
    if (status == 1){
        //TableViewViewController
    } else {
        //Optional StarViewController
    }
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

inside Your App delegate just add Property of you Navigation Controller

```
@property (nonatomic , strong) UINavigationController *navigationController;
```

and Inside

```
-(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions { 

TableViewViewController *TableViewView = [[UIStoryboard
storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil]
instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"TableViewViewController"];


StarViewController *StarView = [[UIStoryboard
storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil]
instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"StarViewController"];


    if (status == 1){  
    self.navigationController =
    [[UINavigationController alloc]
    initWithRootViewController:TableViewView];  
    } else {  
    //Optional
    StarViewController  self.navigationController =
    [[UINavigationController alloc]
    initWithRootViewController:StarView];  
    }  
}
```

instead UINavigationController  you can use you customNavigationcontroller

Comment: Please, [format your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) to make it readable at least, thanks.

Comment: please explain your answer better. I updated my question. @zrzka

Comment: this code will not work. You cast the instanciateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"TableViewViewController" twice to different ViewController classes, and allocate the same UINavigationController with the same. So the code is in total twice written with no effect apart from the casting which goes lost in allocation. And the method does not return anything

Comment: it was a typo error from my side @OlSen thanks mate